# Is there a way to "raw cache" files which docker wants to download

Tags: docker, caching

I know how Docker layers work, but there should be a way independent of layers to allow files which docker downloads to be cached on the local PC, and to manage the cache.

It is very tedious and time-consuming when developing a python app, for example, when adding a new package entry to requirements.txt means Docker must trundle through downloading all the python modules, some of which these days, such as pytorch, are very large!